# In a Tomcat 8 cluster, when are HttpSessionListener methods called?

Tags: tomcat

I have session clustering on Tomcat 8.  Sessions are replicated between different members of the cluster.

I have a `HttpSessionListener` configured.

Will `sessionCreated()` and `sessionDestroyed()` be called on all members of the cluster, or just the member it actually happened on?